# VBA Not Counting, erroring instead

Tags: excel, vba

I'm filtering a spreadsheet that is providing results.  For some reason, it's following the error protocol I have built-in rather than doing what is expected.

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="DED*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="DEX*"
    On Error GoTo Errline1

    Dim Count1 As Range
    Set Count1 = Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

    Dim Line As Range

    For Each Line In Count1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        Count1 = Count1 + Line.Rows.Count
    Next Line
```

I'm expecting this to set Count1 as the number of rows that are visible so I can then use that number as part of an if statement further down.  However, once it gets to the "Next Line" portion, it errors and goes to Errline1

Comment: count1 is a range object. can a number be added to a Range object?

Comment: Very important reading matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Even if it made sense to add a number and a range object, your for-each loop would be mutating `Count1` while simultaneously iterating over it. More often than not, mutating the thing you are iterating over is a bug.

Comment: `Count1` has too many meanings, you're missing a variable somewhere.